# Use inheritance and modify the parameters in some functions

Tags: c#, oop

I need to create math problems. Arithmetic, Comparison 2 numbers.. every class contains similiar features like CheckTheAnswer and GenerateProblem, but each one of them receives different parameters. Here is an example what I'm trying to do.

```
public class Problem<T>
{
    public virtual bool CheckTheAnswer()
    {
        return false;
    }

    public static T GenerateProblem()
    {
        return T;
    }
}

public class Arithmetic : Problem<Arithmetic>
{
    public bool CheckTheAnswer(decimal result)
    {
        ...
    }

    public static Arithmetic GenerateProblem(Tuple<int, decimal, decimal> condition)
    {
        ...
    }
}

public class Comparison2Numbers : Problem<Comparison2Numbers>
{
    public bool CheckTheAnswer(decimal result1, decimal result2)
    {
        ...
    }

    public static Comparison2Numbers GenerateProblem(Tuple<decimal, decimal> condition)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I was thinking in interfaces, but I realized in interfaces can't have static functions.
Thanks in advance.

OK, the question is.. is there a way to do this?

```
Arithmetic a = new Arithmetic();
Problem<Arithmetic> p = a;
```

And get the functions from Arithmetic class. Maybe this is not the best way to generalize this problems, what do you opine?

Comment: I can't see any question

Comment: This won't work at all. You can't override `static` methods, and you can't add/change parameters to `virtual` methods in child classes and still have them be `override`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the behavior of polymorphic creation, the abstract factor pattern would be best for this. See Mark's answer for an example of how to set this up.

But you also need the ability to check the answer with different number of arguments. From your examples, it seem that you will always expect a type of `decimal` for each of the arguments. Assuming this is correct, you can make `CheckTheAnswer` a variadic method. I might also suggest adding a polymorphic property to access the desired number of arguments. So we now have:

```
public abstract class Problem<T>
{
    public abstract int ResultCount { get; }
    public abstract bool CheckTheAnswer(params decimal[] results);
}
```

And the a base class could be along the lines of:

```
public class Arithmetic : Problem<Arithmetic>
{
    public override int ResultCount
    {
        get
        {
            return 2;
        }
    }

    public override bool CheckTheAnswer(params decimal[] results)
    {
        if(results.Length != ResultCount)
            throw new ArgumentException("Only expected " + ResultCount + " arguments.");
        ...
    }
}
```

While this doesn't provide compile-time type safety in the number of arguments, it will allow you to solve your problem using run-time guarantees.

Comment: Well, the parameters won't be always decimal, it'll be better like object. However your idea is very good. I've got two questions: 1 why is better Problem<T> like a abstract class instead of interface? and 2 assuming results is an object array, can I know if the object is integer or double datatype?

Comment: For the first part, that was due to my hastiness. It indeed makes more sense for `Problem<T>` to be an interface. For the second, I have my own question: do you expect all the parameters to be of the same type? Or do you expect mixed types: maybe the first argument is a double, the second an int, the third a decimal, etc? I have two different ideas. Which one is better depends on your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the kind of problem where you probably want an abstract factory for your generators, rather than static methods. You can use the constructors of individual factories to pass in data with varying arguments. Each will have a fixed Create method though.

```
interface IProblemFactory<T> where T : IProblem<T> 
{
    T Create();
}
```

---

```
class ArithmeticProblemFactory : IProblemFactory<Arithmetic> 
{
    private Tuple<int, decimal, decimal> condition;

    public ArithmeticProblemFactory(Tuple<int, decimal, decimal> condition) {
        this.condition = conditionl
    }

    Arithmetic IProblemFactory<Arithmetic>.Create() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Absolutely, I was looking for a way to create these problems. An abstract factory is the best way.